# Opening a html file from python

Tags: python, html

In python 3 code example

```
while cond:      
   .... some code...     
   open html page
```

I want to open local html file(pass parameters to the file) within while condition. So as long as the condition is true the file should keep opening.

These are the following things that I tried:

```
webbrowser.open('path of file')
```

=> with this am not sure of how to pass parameters to the html page

```
return render_template('file.html',params=params)
```

=> the file opens the first time the condition is true but later the loop is not repeated(well I think that the return statement terminates the loop)

Please let me know if I have not posted my question clearly. Awaiting you guidance on this.

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you, we need to understand the problem you are trying to solve. Is this like a macro program you're writing? If it is you might take a look at selenium

Comment: @Rizzit I am writing a code in python and I want it to open a html file as long as the while condition is true

Answer (score 0):

Using the render_template() function, you pass your parameters as a dictionary file mapping from your python variables to the html variables, something like this:

```
name = 'Tony Stark'
workplace = 'Stark Industries'
return render_template('file.html', {name:'name', workplace:'workplace'})
```

The name and workplace in single quotations marks are the variables in your html document usually declared by using the name tag.

To use a while loop:

```
while True:
    webbrowser.open('path to file')
```

work fine.

PS: This render_template is used in development frameworks like django and flask... so i'm not sure if I have answered your question succintly...

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem is am using return render_template() within the while loop. So the while loop terminates when it executes render_template. I want the loop to continue it's action.

Comment: In that case, the return statement does terminate the loop.